# error when running encoding json after fetch

Tags: php, mysql, json

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in /home/content/69/9179269/html/test/json-events.php on line 11

`$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

what would cause this error?

```
`$username = "user";
$password = "psword";

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:localhost;dbname=databasename", $username, $password);

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `time`, `start`, `end`, `url`, `backgroundColor`,    `textColor`, `borderColor`, `description`
    FROM calender WHERE length(column) > 0";`


foreach ($result as $row){
$return[]=array('id'=>$row['id'],
                'title'=>$row['title'],
                'start'=>$row['start'].' '.$row['time'],
                'end'=>$row['end'],
                'url'=>$row['url'],
                'backgroundColor'=>$row['backgroundColor'],
                'textColor'=>$row['textColor'],
                'borderColor'=>$row['borderColor'],
                'description'=>$row['description'],
                "allDay" => false);
}
$dbh = null;

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Try echoing $sql seperately and running it through phpMyAdmin or MySQL Command Line. $dbh->query() will be returning false so fetchAll will fail. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php - PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.

Comment: You're going to need to show more code.

Comment: I updated with all my php code.

Comment: @christian.thomas gives me an error from the length of column > 0

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? Otherwise try LENGTH('column') rather than LENGTH(column)

Comment: I didn't receive any errors when I would single quotes around column. testing actual script now.

Comment: But the syntax is not working, its still pulling blank values into the array...

Answer (score 1):

query() is not returning a pdo statement. That means your query probably failed. Check your sql statement and error message.

Turn on error reporting with

`$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);`

so you can see your error messages.